# Libgdx and third party frameworks on iOS

Tags: ios, libgdx

I want to dive into gaming world. For the developing framework I will probably choose Libgdx framework. I read a lot about it and it seems really great. But there is something I would like to ask.

Can I include third party frameworks into iOS project? I read about RoboVM and some bindings. There are several (included) frameworks on their site (I need some of them), but I would like to include some custom ad network in iOS project (Millenium Media). Can I do that with Libgdx and iOS support? I'm using Android Studio for development. I can include .jar files for android easily, but not .framework files for iOS.

I have RoboVM plugin installed in Android Studio and I sucessfully compiled simple project already. However I don't have a clue how to include third party frameworks.

Comment: You can try to create the binding yourself: [link](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings#how-do-i-create-a-binding). Also, in [this blog post](http://robovm.com/announcing-robopods-cast-your-vote) they mentioned something about "semi-automatic binding generation". But I don't know when will it be ready.